# How do i install a wooden door frame to a brick frame wall?

Tags: walls, doors, brick, frame

What are the process and steps to installing a wooden door frame to a brick frame wall?

Comment: Walls aren't brick (generally speaking). They may have a brick veneer, but they're almost always conventional wood-framed walls behind the brick. Please edit your question to provide much more detail about your scenario. As it is, your question is considered off-topic as either unclear or too broad.

Comment: @isherwood - depends on location. In many (other) countries, brick walls are the norm whereas wood-framed are unusual. GerritNel - tell us where you are and/or clarify if you have a 'solid' brick wall or not.

Comment: Hi there, i am situated in South-Africa and yes i have a solid brick wall.

Comment: Generally there would be wood lats every few feet (in North America at least). I can make some suggestions, however finishing the door will be more of an issue for an amateur installer.

Comment: Can you give me detailed instructions on how you will install this door?

Answer (score 2):

If you're installing the frame in a new wall, then you should have 'tie-wires' embedded into a groove running up each side of the frame.
These are usually L-shaped lengths of galvanised wire about 4mm thick with the short leg of the L embedded in the groove in frame and the long leg sticking out.
The long leg is then embedded into the mortar between courses of bricks in the wall in at least 3 or 4 locations on each side of the frame.
If this is an exterior door then you should also have a strip of "DPC" (plastic sheeting) in the same groove running all around the frame and this keeps water from getting past the frame into the wall.

If you're replacing an existing frame, then it depends on how you've removed that one.
If you've knocked bricks out (or half-bricks) and will be laying new ones then you can continue as if this was a new wall and embed the tie-wires from the door frame into the new mortar between the bricks.
If you've just knocked an existing frame out, but left the brickwork as-is (still a neat rectangle without bits missing), then you'll probably have to drill through the door frame and mount the frame to the bricks with masonry anchors of some sort (something like the things often called 'rawl bolts' in SA). Choose positions where you would drill through into solid brick and not into the mortar between the bricks - those masonry anchors expand when you tighten them and, depending on the strength of the mortar, can sometimes just crack the mortar out of the joint.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed instructions. How do you level the wooden door frame?

Comment: The same way you level anything: with a level. If you're not sure you can accomplish that part, it may be an indication that you lack the skill to complete this task and would benefit from hiring a professional to work alongside you.